# Cypress: Variable isn't seeing the text change I can see in the runner

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

**UPDATE:** ***I'll leave this in case anyone else does the same but while loops don't work in Cypress because Cypress uses asynchronous functions, I got around it by adding a new custom command which checks it the text is present then recursively calls the custom command if true***

I'm trying to reload the page while some text ("Processing") is present in a given selector I've created a function that does the following, you give it the selector to look at, the text you are wanting to look for and the attempts you want to do:

```js
var textFound = Cypress.$(selector).text();
cy.log(textFound) // For this example this is outputting all the text from a tr element I've passed to it

while (textFound.includes(text) && current_attempt <= attempts) {
  cy.log(`we have current attempt: ${current_attempt} `)
  cy.log(`we have selector: ${selector} `)
  cy.log(`we have text found: ${textFound}`)
  cy.log(`we are looking for: ${text}`) // These are outputting the correct values I expect to see the first time round the loop.

  cy.log(`We have text found = ${textFound.includes(text)}`) // outputs true 
  cy.log('reload page clear textfound then set again')
  cy.reload(true);
  textFound = 'Cleared'
  cy.log(`we have text found: ${textFound}`) // outputs Cleared
  cy.log(`Get textFound again`)
  textFound = Cypress.$(selector).text();
  cy.log(`we have text found: ${textFound}`) // Outputs the tr again
  cy.log('wait 30 seconds')
  current_attempt++
  cy.wait(30000);
}
```

The problem is when I run the test eventually after about 1 minute I can see in the Cypress runner the TR no longer contains text "Processing" and it's not present anywhere else on the page, but when I'm setting textFound in the loop again it still contains "Processing" and doesn't show "Success" which is what I can see in the Cypress runner.

Can anyone think of a reason the code doesn't pick up the change but I can see it in the runner?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn`t work is, because Cypress declares variables that are just [Values](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/) before the test starts and are not accessible in the code unless declared and used in a callback or alliased. On the other hand it works well with [References](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/) like object/array.

To store variables I use [alliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) or object:

```
let variables = {}
cy.get('elementSelector')
   .then($el => {
      //as allias
      cy.wrap($el.text()).as('variableName')

      //As object key
     variables.variableINeed = $el.text()
   })

// To call the variable as allias
cy.get('@variableName')
  .then(variable => {//code to use it})   

//To call the variable from object
cy.get('elementToCheck')
   .should('contain', variables.variableINeed)
```